# I'm getting, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java

This is the class where the error is shown. 
I have commented the line number 245, where netbeans says: dereferencing possible null pointer. if i didn't initialize the endHours as null, it also gives an error. and when i print endHour, it clearly returns a value. but i get this error when i try to put the endHour to the array endHours

```
public List getRanges(String type) throws NullPointerException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    List endHours = null;


    String fileName="";
    if(type.equals("tcp")){
        fileName="tcprange";
    }else if(type.equals("udp")){
        fileName="udprange";
    }

    String line = null;

    try {

        FileReader fileReader=new FileReader("conf/"+fileName+".txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        int i=0;
        HashMap tempEndHours=new HashMap();
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            int endHour=0;
            String[] split=line.split("\t");
            endHour=Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            if(!tempEndHours.containsKey(endHour)){
                tempEndHours.put(tempEndHours,i);
                //System.out.println(endHour);
                endHours.add(i,endHour);// ** line 245
            }
            //System.out.println(endHour);

            i++;

        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '"+"conf/"+type+".txt"+ "'");                
    }

    //Collections.sort(endHours);
    return endHours;
}
```

Comment: Where is `endHours` defined?

Comment: Can you please post all the relevant code and point out the line that the exception occurs?

Comment: We cannot see your IDE's line numbers

Comment: yeas, i commented the line number in the code "endHours.add(i,endHour); //line 245".

Comment: Where is the confusion? You wrote `List endHours = null;` and then you wonder why `endHours` is `null`?

Comment: @Tom if i don't initialize the List endHours as null, it gives another error.

Comment: Please read the link of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate `endHours`

```
public List<Integer> getRanges(String type) throws NullPointerException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    List<Integer> endHours = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm new to java. thanx a lot again

Answer (score 0):

may be, in your `endHour` you are getting a null value. your performing add operation on it so, your getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`, check for null. and give us full stack trace of your exception.

Comment: Null values are allowed in a list. (Assuming endHours is a List)